# How do I change default style of Breadcrumb in Chakra?

Tags: chakra-ui

I have a breadcrumb:

```
<Breadcrumb
  spacing="8px"
  separator={<ChevronRightIcon color="gray.500" />}
>
  <BreadcrumbItem>
    <BreadcrumbLink href="/meetings">Meetings</BreadcrumbLink>
  </BreadcrumbItem>

  <BreadcrumbItem isCurrentPage>
    <BreadcrumbLink href="#">{meeting.name}</BreadcrumbLink>
  </BreadcrumbItem>
</Breadcrumb>
```

I would like to style this in my Chakra theme.

I managed to change the color like this:

```
const Breadcrumb = {
  variants: {
    customTheme: {
      link: {
        color: "coarseWoolOpacity.700",
      },
    },
  },
  defaultProps: {
    variant: "customTheme",
  },
}

...
const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    ...
  },
  components: {
    ...
    Breadcrumb,
  },
  colors,
  fonts,
})

export default theme
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to make the `isCurrentPage` different or apply the CheveronRightIcon separator on the theme level.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { breadcrumbAnatomy } from '@chakra-ui/anatomy'
import { ComponentStyleConfig, defineStyleConfig } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { createMultiStyleConfigHelpers } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const { definePartsStyle, defineMultiStyleConfig } =
createMultiStyleConfigHelpers(breadcrumbAnatomy.keys)

export const baseStyle = definePartsStyle((props) => {
console.log('props', props)
return {
    container: {
        border: '1px solid red',
    },
    item: {
        border: '1px solid green',
    },
    link: {
        border: '1px solid gold',
    },
    separator: {
        border: '1px solid tomato',
    },
}
})
export const Breadcrumb = defineMultiStyleConfig({ baseStyle })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).